# Label encoding using sklearn python start from 1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encode

I wanna ask about how to convert categorical features to numerical using sklearn python beginning from 1 not 0.

Thank you

Comment: You can just add 1 to the result no?

Comment: how to add 1 to the result? @EdChum

Comment: Post your code, I/we are not able to deduce your code from this vague description

Comment: Thank you for ur help, I already solve my problem. Then, I wanna ask again what should I do to convert categorical data such >100 or <80 to numerical data if in that case my data looks like " 31.8, 26.8, 13.5, 36.2, >100, 80, <20" ? Actually, I wanna do classification using Naive Bayes. Most of my data are numerical but some of them are not. If I just convert all of them using  LabelEncoder (skicit learn) as usual, it will change my numerical data too. @EdChum

Comment: Sorry but I can't answer your question via comments, you need to post your raw data, your code that loads this data, what the desired result is and your attempts including any errors. SO is not a forum.

Comment: Sorry but I think you don't understand how SO  works, you don't post code in comments, you post it in your question. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: okay, thank you for your help :) @EdChum

Comment: yeah, I am still newbie here :D @EdChum Thanks for your explanation :)